# Horizontal ViewPager with vertical gallery in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gallery

I have catalog of products with IDs `1...n` and each product have 5 different variations: a, b, c, d, e (images).

I'm looking for a way how implement it. For switching between product good idea is `ViewPager` - horizontal, but how to implement variations - vertical? Both `ViewPager` and variations should work on the same object - image (gray on pic below).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pvTk5OT.png]

How can I accomplish this?